# Why doesn't Elm provide HTML document head tags?

Tags: html, dom, elm

Elm does not appear to support HTML document's head node, `<head>..</head>`.

The question is why not support the complete HTML document with suitable functions. It would seem such an inclusion would allow expedient use of external resources such as style sheets.

Apart from `DOCTYPE`, HTML tags are uniformly, `tagName attrList elmList`. Perhaps a set of `appendAttr` and `appendElm` functions could be concocted to allow flexibility for specifying a more comprehensive `VirtualDom`.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I am new to Elm, but as I understand, you would not compile Elm to HTML for a production site.  You would compile to JS instead: `elm make /path/to/Main.elm --output='main.js'` and then include that JS file in your HTML file.  Maybe the reason Evan did not support the `<head>` node was because it is not necessary, but I don't know the reason.

Comment: Raphael, `elm make /path/to/Main.elm` actually generates a `index.html` by default, which is a proper `html` document complete with `<!DOCTYPE html><head>...</head><body>...</body>`.

Answer (score 7):

By the time that your Elm code has loaded and starts running, the browser has already read in the `<head>` of the HTML page that contains the Elm code, so it's too late to influence the contents of the `<head>`.

Elm can be embedded into an element in the page, or run full-screen (which appears to add a child to the `<body>`).  Elm can only manipulate content within its container, not outside of it.  In particular, all elements that Elm generates will be contained within the `<body>` of the document, whereas `<head>` is a sibling of `<body>`.

It's possible to generate HTML elements with any name you like, using `Html.node "elementName"`.  So it's possible to create a `<head>` element in Elm.  However, a `<head>` element created this way would end up inside `<body>`, and I would expect browsers to ignore it.

Comment: I don't think Html.node can produce <!DOCTYPE html>. It would be nice if it could...

Comment: @George: turns out I was wrong about elm-reactor. That will make up a basic HTML page and stick the Elm code in the body.  So I've rolled my answer back to the previous revision, which I now believe to be more accurate.

Comment: granted, an initial page cannot be designed by Elm; however, the JavaScript document model does expose the `<head>` element, event the `<html>` to which, like the rest of it, the html module may be coded to wrap...perhaps with the function...`node` as you say...

Answer (score 6):

Luke's answer is of course perfectly correct, but nothing prevents you updating the head of a document using javascript via a port. Here is an example to update the title (the tab name).

**In Elm**

```
port module Ports exposing (..)

port title : String -> Cmd msg
```

with this sort of update function

```
update message model = 
    case message of 
        SetTitle name ->
            (model, Ports.title name)
```

**In Javascript**

```
var elm = Main.fullscreen();

elm.ports.title.subscribe( title => {
    document.title = title;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Elm is a (mostly) purely functional language, meaning it attempts to minimize all side effects that could lead to errors.  As the elm compiler has no way to know if a CSS file will exist at runtime, it cannot safely say whether or not including a CSS file will result in an error.  Therefore, it is not something that will likely be included in the future.

That being said, Rtfeldman of NoRedInk has created the repo https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-css that allows for elm code to mirror CSS, ensuring safety as it goes.

To make your body have a background color with a certain color, this elm code suffices:

```
[ body
    [ backgroundColor (rgb 200 128 64)
    , color (hex "CCFFFF")
    ]
]
```

and will compile to a `.css` file for you.

Comment: Actually, Elm is a pure functional language. This means, variables are immutable and all functions are typed dictionaries where all key values have a valid result. Thus, a guarantee against fault becomes a simple type consistency check at compile time. In particular, you can affirm that compiled Elm code will produces a valid value (`Html a`, `Cmd a`, `Sub a`) based on all possible input (`Msg`) barring stack overflow or memory full errors, of course. The runtime may have additional guarantees; however, these do not extend to the web or browser or referenced resources such as CSS.

Comment: Eh. Elm allows the running of Native Modules (such as Debug.log) that are written in JavaScript and have no guarantees. As long as Native JavaScript can be run via elm function calls, it is not completely 100% pure.